# Vim: how to use variables in vimrc?

Tags: variables, vim

here what I am trying to do, a simple function to increment a global variable. It works fine.

```
let g:high_ind = 1

fun! IncHighlightInd()
  let g:high_ind = (g:high_ind + 1) %10
  return g:high_ind
endf
```

I want to use this variable in a `map`

```
map <C-h> :call IncHighlightInd() <CR> :Highlight g:high_ind <CR>
```

But `g:high_ind` is not recognized as a variable. How to use this variable?

Or more interestingly, is it possible to do something like the below?

```
map <C-h> :Highlight IncHighlightInd() <CR>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use :exe or c_CTRL-R_=:

```
nnoremap <c-h> :exe ":Highlight ".IncHighLightInd()<cr>
nnoremap <c-h> :Highlight <c-r>=IncHighLightInd()<cr><cr>
```

BTW, I suspect you should have a look at this page: [Highlight multiple words](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words) on vim.wikia.